# Setting up a DDNS server that updates through HTTP POST requests

Tags: post, https, dns, webserver

Good afternoon!

I need to set up a remote Dynamic DNS (DDNS) server to which I can remotely add/remove/update records.

The way I think this could work is by setting up a server, having it run the DDNS daemon, and also have it run a basic web server to process http POST requests.

The POST requests would tell the web server how to alter the DNS records.

I have the following questions:

1. Is there an already-made (free!) service that meets the above specifications?
2. If not, is my plan above viable? Is it the best way to go around?
3. Do you have any tips/hints/advice I should heed before implementing this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You may be reinventing the wheel, nsupdate is already capable of this without involving a POST request: http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.10.0b1/doc/arm/man.nsupdate.html

Comment: @RickBuford I appologize for not having seen your comment. The issue has been resolved, but I appreciate the time you took to read my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your need publicly visible address, you must have a public DNS server as **'authoritative'** (ie master) . <sup>(1)</sup>
You will need a DNS server (BIND or similar) and a basic web service running on the same box, then you can post to a specially crafted page. There, from the page request, you get the remote IP address, the 'domain' (if the page is used by more than one domain), parse whatever additional parameters on your query string and then update your DNS server records.

To publish I use 'wget' and for a (basic) security added a 'secret' key and the remote (unique) mac address:

```
mac=`(/sbin/ifconfig eth0| /bin/grep HWaddr | /usr/bin/awk -F'HWaddr' '{ print $2 }' )`
wget -o /dev/null -O reply.txt "server.mydomain.com/page?key=aF6tw3&mac=$mac&host=$(hostname)&data=data...."
```

I have this setting, using 'cron' and also on 'if-up'  running for a few years with no issues.

<sub>(1) You can purchase a cheap domain and then point the 'ns' records to your own server.</sub>

Comment: I appreciate the response, I indeed built something very similar to your description!